# How do I write multicol in Lyx on the title page?

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to write some text in two columns on the `titlepage`, but unfortunately everytime the `tabular` part is on a new page with a blank page between. I guess it has something to do with `\maketitle`, but how do I change that in LyX?

P.S. Multicols doesnt work too

```
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}


\title{randomTitle}


\subject{1. bla}


\date{vorgelegt am \today}

\begin{doublespace}

\publishers{\noindent Fakultät Wirtschaft \smallskip{}
\\
Studiengang Wirtschaftsinformatik\smallskip{}
\\
Kurs }
\end{doublespace}


\author{von \smallskip{}
\\
user1259201}

\maketitle

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Verfasser: \\\ Ich      
Ausbildungsbetrieb:\\\myCompany         
Anschrift:\\\ myCompanyAddressStreet\\      

Betreuer:\\\myProf  
Abgabedatum:\\\myEndDate    
\end{tabular}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for the document class you use (I guess a KOMA class, report [`scrrprt`] or book [`scrbook`]), the stuff generated by `\maketitle` is put on a page by itself, so any material you add immediately after it will come on the following page.

A kind of hackish way of doing this is to add the tabular within the last element of the `\maketitle`. Of the things you included, the `\publishers` is the last, so you could add the tabular at the end of this, with some vertical space first, e.g.

```
\publishers{%
Fakultät Wirtschaft \\
Studiengang Wirtschaftsinformatik \\
Kurs\\[2cm]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Verfasser: & Ich   \\
  Ausbildungsbetrieb: & myCompany \\
  Anschrift: & myCompanyAddressStreet \\
  Betreuer: & myProf  \\
  Abgabedatum: & myEndDate 
\end{tabular}
}
```

Another way is to *not* use `\author`, `title` etc. and `\maketitle`, and instead create the titlepage manually.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that tonight! You are right, I use scrbook. I should have posted that too

Comment: That helped! I did the hackish way ;)